# Babelify "use strict" issue with gulp and jsx

Tags: reactjs, gulp, babeljs

I want to remove strict mode i.e "use strict" from common js made by gulp.

I tried

```
browserify({
            debug: true,
            entries: ['src/Components/Main.jsx']
        })
        //.transform(["babelify",{presets: ["stage-0", "stage-1", "es2015", "react"],  blacklist: [ 'useStrict' ]}])
        .transform(babelify.configure({
          presets: ["stage-0", "stage-1", "es2015", "react", "transform-strict-mode"],
        }))
        .bundle()
```

But getting this error

Error: Couldn't find preset "transform-strict-mode" relative to directory. I installed it

```
npm install babel-plugin-transform-strict-mode
```

and it is installed in the same directory where other preset is installed.

I also tried

```
.transform(["babelify",{presets: ["stage-0", "stage-1", "es2015", "react"],  blacklist: [ 'useStrict' ]}])
```

But not working..

can anybody please help me with this.

I am unable to comment on stack overflow . stack overflow is not letting me to comment anywhere so I will not able to reply in comment.

**Edit :**

```
.transform( 'babelify', {
  presets: [ 'stage-0', 'react', ],
  plugins: [ 'transform-strict-mode' ]
})
```

is working but I want to remove strict mode . So I am trying it with options like this:

```
.transform(babelify.configure({
          presets: ["stage-0",  "react"],
          plugins: ["transform-strict-mode", {"strict": false}]
        }))
```

and it is giving  this error

```
Plugin 1 specified in "base" provided an invalid property of "strict" while parsing
```

Comment: You want to remove it? The plugin that you're trying to use adds it in: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-strict-mode/.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding it as a preset when it is a plugin

Something like the following should fix it

```
.transform( 'babelify', {
  presets: [ 'stage-0', 'react', ],
  plugins: [ 'transform-strict-mode' ]
})
```

Also, you dont need to include `stage-1` and `es2015` presets, they are included with `stage-0`.